# Check if commit hash is only included in a branch on a remote repo

Tags: git, go, github

##### We have two github repos. Let's call them `RepoA` and `RepoB`

`RepoB` imports go code from `RepoA`.  So if we want a feature in `RepoB` we create a branch in `RepoA`, make the changes and then create other changes in RepoB which imports those updates from RepoA from the feature branch.

e.g.
RepoA (github.com/example/repoa)
RepoB (github.com/example/repob)

github.com/example/repob/main.go:

```
import "github.com/example/repoa/thing"

func callA(){
  /// use function exported from repoa
}
```

We then go through a bunch of tech reviews and finally a QA test before merging to our main development branch

#### The problem occurs during the merging process

We have a number of workflows that build and test the output.
We have the feature to delete the branch after it's merged turned on for both github repos.
If a developer merges repob first to the main branch, it will all work fine initially.

But later, someone will create a branch off the the main branch in `repoB` they will quickly discover that it doesn't build because the repoA commit referred to has been merged and the branch deleted.

We then get errors like these in our build CI pipeline.

```
go: github.com/example/repoa/thing@v0.0.0-20220930090610-b4f59a02e13d: invalid version: unknown revision b4f59a02e13d
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

To prevent this problem, I'm wanting to create a tool that runs on `repoB` github action that checks if
`github.com/example/repoa/thing` with commit hash `b4f59a02e13d` (as in the example above) is on one of our approved branches.

Namely: `main`, `develop` or `release/*`

If not, then it exit with return code 1.   If all OK, it'll have exit code 0

#### How do I do this?

I think I can figure out the workflow.  But the github side of it I'm not sure without checking out the entire repo.

Essentially I would go through every repo in go.mod that has prefix "github.com/example"
Then run the tool on the referenced commit hash and check the output.

The idea being if I get a one, then I can prevent merging.  If I get a zero, then merging is ok.  Essentially forcing the merge order so as not to break things.

I hope this makes sense.   I think this is easier than trying to create some kind of automated PR creation to update the commit hash for the go.mod.  My solution would not require any extra PR's but would force proper process on the developer doing the merge.

This is I think the command that I would want.  How do I make it run on a repo that I don't have checked out?

```
git branch -a --contains b4f59a02e13d
remotes/origin/refactor/EE-4342/stack-build-process-backend-only
```

In the above case, there is no "main", "develop" or "release/*" pattern in the output.  So we should prevent the dev from merging.
But to run this command I need to clone the repo first which isn't ideal.

Comment: In general, you must keep and update a client-side clone here. For GitHub specifically, there *might* be some API call you can make (and if not you could petition GitHub to add one), but that won't work on non-GitHub repositories.